# PowerShell: Create a function that i can use as a powershell command in the future

Tags: windows, powershell

**My Goal**

---

To create a function in powershell, that searches for a partial matching of a string within a file (and recursively in subfiles if i add this as a parameter).

The function i have works in the IDE, however **how do i make this function as a cmdlet command available globally?**

**My Solution**

---

My Solution until now is the following command that does the search:

> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.md

And if I want to search recursively in the substrucutres

> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.md -Recurse

```
function own_find()
{
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
       [string]$searchResult = "",
       [bool]$Recurse = 0
)

if ($Recurse -eq 0)
{
    Write-Output "You are searching in the direct child and not in recursively in the subdirectories"
    $Result = Get-ChildItem -Filter $searchResult
}
elseif ($Recurse -eq 1)
{
    Write-Output "You are searching with the -Recurse method in subdirectories."
    $Result = Get-ChildItem -Filter $searchResult -Recurse
}


if ($Result)
    {
    Write-Output "Results found"
    Write-Output "============="
    return $Result
    }
else 
    {
    Write-Output "No results found. Maybe your search string was wrong. Use * as placeholders"
    }
   Export-ModuleMember -Function own_find
}
```

**It works!**

---

**My Question**

Where should i store the file or what should I do in order to make this function available globally in Powershell without importing a module or sth like that?

Comment: You can [put it in a profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your PowerShell profile, which is a script that is run every time PowerShell loads on a system.

If you don't have a profile, you can make one, like so:

```
"" > $PROFILE
notepad $PROFILE
```

then paste your function into the window.  I have a lot of commands stored in mine.  So many that I forget them sometimes, so I also end my profile with this little snippet.

```
"Custom Commands"
get-content $profile | select-string ^function | %{
     write-host -fore Cyan ($_.Line.Replace("Function",'').Replace("{",''))
     }
```

That results in this output:

```
Custom Commands
 Get-MOTD
 Toggle-Debug
 Set-FireWallPublicExclusion
 Out-Notepad
 Search-Google
 Uptime
 diskusage
 patches
 Play-Bubble
 Get-Weather
 Get-SwitchedStatus
 Split-N-Trim
 Move-RecallUsers
 RemindMe-MSOL
 RemindMe-Comparators
 RemindMe-Git
 Get-BabyCam1
 Get-BabyCam2
 remove-dockerContainers
```